# How to edit encoded json file in Python

Tags: python, json, encoding, discord.py

I'm currently developping a Discord bot with Python. To save data, I have created a .tmp file that store a json format text of data.

I had to encoded it in order to write immediatly in the file (I also do some  value check in the file).

Because it's encoded, I'm unable to edit the json with this code :

```
emojiU = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
emojiD = '\N{THUMBS DOWN SIGN}'
cnd_Member = [member for member in ctx.guild.members if str(data['roles_id']['AmongUs']) in str(member.roles) and (str(member.status) == "online" or str(member.status) == "idle") and member.id != ctx.author.id]
tmpfile = open("my_file.tmp", "wb+", 0) #List that store connected user with a specific role

for i, member in enumerate(cnd_Member): # for connected member with the specific role

    DM = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id=member.id)
    Sstring = "***" + Sender + "***" + '   veux jouer à  ***' + game + '***.\n :thumbsup:  si vous êtes chaud ou  :thumbsdown:  si vous ne l\'êtes pas'
    msg = await DM.send(embed=createEbd(des=Sstring, img=imgLink)) #send DM to the member

    if i == 0:
       save = '{{"{}":{{"msgId":{}, "reaction":"None"}}, '.format(member.id, msg.id)

    elif i == len(list(cnd_Member))-1:
         save = '"{}":{{"msgId":{}, "reaction":"None"}}}}'.format(member.id, msg.id)

    else :
         save = '"{}":{{"msgId":{}, "reaction":"None"}}, '.format(member.id, msg.id)

    await msg.add_reaction(emojiU ) #Bot add reaction to the DM message
    await msg.add_reaction(emojiD) #Bot add reaction to the DM message
    tmpfile.write(save.encode("utf-8")) #creating the json file with data


    @client.event
    async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
          
          if user.id != client.user.id :
             if reaction.emoji == emojiU:
                tmpfile.seek(0)
                rd = tmpfile.read() # Getting the content of file 
                binf = json.loads(rd.decode('utf-8'))


                binf["{}".format(user.id)]["msgId"] = thxObj.id   #Updating the json with new value
                binf["{}".format(user.id)]["reaction"] = "True"   #Updating the json with new value

                json.dump(binf, tmpfile) #writing to file fail because it's not encoded

          
             if reaction.emoji == emojiD:
                tmpfile.seek(0)
                rd = tmpfile.read() # Getting the content of file 
                binf = json.loads(rd.decode('utf-8'))


                binf["{}".format(user.id)]["msgId"] = thxObj.id   #Updating the json with new value
                binf["{}".format(user.id)]["reaction"] = "False"   #Updating the json with new value

                json.dump(binf, tmpfile) #writing to file fail because it's not encoded
```

Using json.dumps then encoding it and write it in file with tmpfile.write works but it only append data, not editing the existing json in the tmpfile.

Thanks for help

Comment: Your code look more like pseudo code, could you provide example at least without syntax errors?

Comment: Open a new write handle, so you can be sure you're overwriting. Or write it to a temp file and swap them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to deal with it.

I stored all data in JSON format file, when a user adds a reaction it edits the file.
When I need to publish the table it reads the JSON file.

Encoded or not encoded, I just had to edit the `json.loads` and rewrite the file and it worked